# How to store date into Mysql database with play framework in scala?

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am working with play framework with scala and

**what am i doing** :

1. login page to login into web app
2. sign up page to register into web app
3. after login i want to store all databases values to user

**what i want to do**:

when user register for web app then i want to store user values into database with current time and date but my form is giving error.

**error:**

```
List(FormError(dates,error.required,List())),None)
```

**controllers/Application.scala**

```
object Application extends Controller {

  val ta:Form[Keyword] = Form(
          mapping(
    "id" -> ignored(NotAssigned:Pk[Long]),
    "word" -> nonEmptyText,
    "blog" -> nonEmptyText,
    "cat" -> nonEmptyText,
    "score"-> of[Long],
    "summaryId"-> nonEmptyText,
    "dates" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  )(Keyword.apply)(Keyword.unapply)
  )

  def index = Action {
    Ok(html.index(ta));
  }

def newTask=  Action { implicit request =>
  ta.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => {println(errors) 
      BadRequest(html.index(errors))},
    keywo => {

      Keyword.create(keywo)
      Ok(views.html.data(Keyword.all()))
    }
  )
}
```

**models/keyword.scala**

case class Keyword(id: Pk[Long],word: String,blog: String,cat: String,score: Long, summaryId: String,dates: Date )

```
object Keyword {

 val keyw = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("keyword.id") ~
     get[String]("keyword.word")~
    get[String]("keyword.blog")~
    get[String]("keyword.cat")~
    get[Long]("keyword.score") ~ 
    get[String]("keyword.summaryId")~
    get[Date]("keyword.dates") map {
    case id~blog~cat~word~score~summaryId~dates => Keyword(id,word,blog,cat,score, summaryId,dates)
  }
}
  def all(): List[Keyword] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  SQL("select * from keyword").as(Keyword.keyw *)
}

def create(key: Keyword){DB.withConnection{implicit c=> 
  SQL("insert into keyword values({word},{blog}, {cat}, {score},{summaryId},{dates})").on('word-> key.word,'blog->key.blog,
      'cat -> key.cat,
      'score-> key.score,
      'summaryId -> key.summaryId,
      'dates->new Date()).executeUpdate
}
}
```

views/index.scala.html

```
@(taskForm: Form[Keyword])

@import helper._

@main("Todo list") {



    @form(routes.Application.newTask) {


    @inputText(taskForm("word"))
        @inputText(taskForm("blog"))
        @inputText(taskForm("cat"))
        @inputText(taskForm("score"))
        @inputText(taskForm("summaryId")) 

        <input type="submit">

        <a href="">Go Back</a>
    }


}
```

please give me some idea to store date into mysql databse and date is not a field of form

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:
1. Hidden text field with date(that you override when saving)
2. Have a separate class for the form and dbTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for your `dates` field in the form by replacing `"dates" -> date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` with `"dates" -> ignored(new Date())`. This will ignore any posted data for "dates" and automatically bind it to `new Date()` (or any value you provide it).